# When will Visual Studio Local pane show C++ base type instead of real type and how to fix?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Suppose some C++ class "SubClass" extends class "BaseClass", then when debugging the program in VS2017 and break at some break point in some member function of either classes, in the "Local" pane of VS2017, the "Type" column of "this" should show "SubClass" (i.e. the real type, not some base type) if "this" is an instance of "SubClass".

But sometimes for some complex application this doesn't work and it show the name of the base class for the type of "this" if the break point is in some method of the base class.

When will this happen and how can it be fixed?

Appendix:

One example is to debug clang 6.0 in VS2017 and set a breakpoint in the method

```
void MCObjectStreamer::EmitFrames(MCAsmBackend *MAB)
```

in MCObjectStreamer.cpp. When break, the type of "this" is shown as "llvm:MCObjectStreamer", but "this" is indeed some sub class "X86WinCOFFStreamer". Go one step upstream in the call stack and in the method (of the sub class X86WinCOFFStreamer)

```
void X86WinCOFFStreamer::FinishImpl()
```

"this" is shown rightly as "X86WinCOFFStreamer"

Comment: Does the base class have (at least) one virtual method? If it does not, it is impossible for the debugger in the context of `MCObjectStreamer` to know the derived class type (`dynamic_cast` would fail as well).

Comment: @prapin The direct base class doesn't have one, but MCObjectStreamer have. X86WinCOFFStreamer extends MCWinCOFFStreamer(no virtual) extends MCObjectStreamer (have virtual)

Comment: @prapin Plus the content of "this" in either case will finally lead to the most base class's __vfptr. MCObjectStreamer extends MCStreamer which is the most base class.